# How to capture log of git fsck --full --verbose

Tags: git, shell, csh, io-redirection, git-fsck

How do I capture output of `git fsck --full --verbose` in a log file?

I tried with

```
git fsck --full --verbose > log
```

and

```
git fsck --full --verbose | tee log
```

but neither is working for me. What should I do?

Comment: I have this problem too despite using `2>&1 | tee /tmp/out.log`

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by switching to bash from csh.

Comment: What was the issue? You meant that CSH doesn't support pipes/redirection?